# Replace values in expression and perform operations on the replaced values in python format()

Tags: python

I am having an expression like 'a{year}-b{year-1}' and the value of 'year' can be any integer value and I want to replace the 'year' in the expression with whatever value of 'year' I have.

So when I tried to do

```
    expression = 'a{year}-b{year-1}'
    new_exp = expression.format(year=2001)
```

It's giving me KeyError: 'year-1'

Is it possible to get 'a2001-b2000'?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Do you want this ``expression = 'a{}-b{}'.format(year,year-1)``?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, it works but the expression might have more than two terms and i can't pass all those as values in format(). I am looking for an answer where i can just provide value for year and it will automatically be handled..

Answer (score 0):

I write a fool class and function can do this:(I find it won't cover the original `format` function.)

```
class expression:
    @staticmethod
    def format(year):
        return "a{}-b{}".format(year,year-1)

print(expression.format(year=2001))
```

Or you can use this,only pass one argument:

```
expression = lambda year:"a{}-b{}".format(year,year-1)
print(expression(year=2001))
```